SwiftGeneratePch normal arm64 Compiling\ bridging\ header
I encountered an error with the title while building a TrollStore installer ,I directly cloned the original warehouse using Git、Github Page
、
I encountered a title error while directly running build.sh to build this project. Due to limited understanding of the XCode project, I am unsure how to resolve the error. I have checked the build settings and tried many options. I hope to find some solutions to similar cases here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

13 errors generated
:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/mrxi/Downloads/TX/TrollInstallerX/DerivedData/TrollInstallerX/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/TrollInstallerX-Bridging-Header-swift_3H0DLJN4RDZU0-clang_XFJBT2N944N7.pch' for bridging header '/Users/mrxi/Downloads/TX/TrollInstallerX/TrollInstallerX/TrollInstallerX-Bridging-Header.h'
26 errors generated.
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
SwiftGeneratePch normal arm64 Compiling\ bridging\ header (in target 'TrollInstallerX' from project 'TrollInstallerX')
(1 failure)
